# How to disable the extra white space between code and comments in eslint/prettier?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, prettier

I have a project using eslint/prettier with node/typescipt

and this is my code

[image]

and my `.prettierrc.yaml` file.

```
singleQuote: true
semi: true
printWidth: 100
trailingComma: none
endOfLine: auto
```

how can I disable the extra white space warning?

Comment: Does this happen even if you use tabs instead?

Comment: yes it does have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can. Prettier is [highly] "opinionated". You can pretty much take their way or the highway.

[Needless to say, I disagree vehemently with Prettier's philosophy (and choices). Style matters. And, I agree with you. Alignment matters: it enhances both readability and understanding.]

https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html

> **Option Philosophy**
>
> > Prettier has a few options because of history.
> > But we won’t add more of them.
> >
> > Read on to learn more.
>
> Prettier is not a kitchen-sink code formatter that attempts to print your
> code in any way you wish. It is opinionated.
> Quoting the *Why Prettier?* page:
>
> > By far the biggest reason for adopting Prettier is to stop all the
> > ongoing debates over styles.
>
> Yet the more options Prettier has, the further from the above goal it
> gets. **The debates over styles just turn into debates over which Prettier
> options to use.** Formatting wars break out with renewed vigour: “Which
> option values are better? Why? Did we make the right choices?”
>
> And it’s not the only cost options have. To learn more about their
> downsides, see the issue about resisting adding configuration, which has
> more s than any option request issue.
>
> So why are there any options at all?
>
> - A few were added during Prettier’s infancy to make it take off at all.
> - A couple were added after “great demand.”
> - Some were added for compatibility reasons.
>
> **. . .**
>
> For a long time, we left option requests open in order to let discussions
> play out and collect feedback. What we’ve learned during those years is
> that it’s really hard to measure demand. Prettier has grown a lot in
> usage. What was “great demand” back in the day is not as much today.
> GitHub reactions and Twitter polls became unrepresentative. What about all
> silent users? It looked easy to add “just one more” option. But where
> should we have stopped? When is one too many? Even after adding “that one
> final option”, there would always be a “top issue” in the issue tracker.
>
> However, the time to stop has come. Now that Prettier is mature enough and
> we see it adopted by so many organizations and projects, the research
> phase is over. We have enough confidence to conclude that Prettier reached
> a point where the set of options should be “frozen”. Option requests
> aren’t accepted anymore. We’re thankful to everyone who participated in
> this difficult journey.
>
> Please note that as option requests are out of scope for Prettier, they
> will be closed without discussion. The same applies to requests to
> preserve elements of input formatting (e.g. line breaks) since that’s
> nothing else but an option in disguise with all the downsides of “real”
> options. There may be situations where adding an option can’t be avoided
> because of technical necessity (e.g. compatibility), but for
> formatting-related options, this is final.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, and I haven't found any config for that purpose. I think we just can use `// prettier-ignore`: [link](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#javascript) after applied all fix (eslint-prettier fix then your intention fix).
It will ignore (all) prettier's rule but eslint still working. Just for that special purpose code block.